# Is it possible to search a numbers by Sphinx quickly than by MySQL?

Tags: sphinx

I need to find one row where the timestamp 'nearest or equal' to query?

```
CREATE TABLE test ( date TIMESTAMP(6) UNIQUE, num INT(32) );
| 2018-07-02 05:50:33.084011 |  282 |
| 2018-07-02 05:50:33.084028 |  475 |
```

(40 M such rows... all timestamps is unique, so this column are unique index)

sphinx.conf:

```
source src1
{
    type = mysql
    ...        
    sql_query = SELECT * FROM test
}

# indexer...
Sphinx 3.0.3
...
indexing index 'test'...
collected 10000000 docs, 0.0 MB
```

In my test I find nearest timestamp to query:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$query = '2018-07-02 05:50:33.084011';
$connMySQL = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','','');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE date <= '$search' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
$que  = $connMySQL->query($sql);
$result = $que->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r ($result);
echo 'Time MySQL:'.(microtime(true) - $start).' sec.';

$start = microtime(true);
$query = '2018-07-02 05:50:33.084028';
$connSphinxQL = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=9306;dbname=test','root','');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE date <= '$search' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
$que  = $connSphinxQL->query($sql);
$result = $que->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r ($result);
echo 'Time Sphinx:'.(microtime(true) - $start).' sec.';
```

Output:

```
[date] => 2018-07-02 05:50:33.084011 [num] => 282 Time: 0.00193 sec.
[date] => 2018-07-02 05:50:33.084028 [num] => 475 Time: 0.00184 sec.
```

Comment: So in MySql do you also have that in one field or in billion lines? What's your mysql query then?

Comment: In MySQL there is a billion lines. Every line contents a hundreds fields. I need in searching only per one field now.

Comment: Think still ask for the SQL query itself. Not clear if Lines is rows, or a single cell in a row, with newlines

Comment: add an index, `ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX(num)` should allow for pretty quick queries in MYSQL. `SELECT * FROM test WHERE num BETWEEN 3 AND 7` or even with you edit, `SELECT * FROM test WHERE num <= 5 ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Actually, my second (and first for thar matter) MySQL query, work perfectly well as SPHINXQL.